# Python function is returning incorrect data

Tags: python, recursion

The code below, when referenced in a separate file is returning incorrect data. When given data that does not match the if/else statements, it will loop through the function again, but the variable in the other file (client_type) will still be the incorrect choice.

function:

```
def create_client():
    client_type = input()

    if client_type == 'Mickey':
        return 'Mickey'
    elif client_type == 'Jenny':
        return 'Jenny'
    elif client_type == 'McElroy':
        return 'McElroy'
    else:
        create_client()
```

call to the function:

```
client_type = functions.create_client()

if client_type == 'Mickey':
    client = functions.client(3, 5, 2)
elif client_type == 'Jenny':
    client = functions.client(5, 2, 3)
elif client_type == 'McElroy':
    client = functions.client(4, 1, 5)
else:
    print('Error on choosing client in function create_client.')
```

Comment: `return create_client()`, or try a while loop instead of recursing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when your function recurses, it returns nothing.

You should change

```
else:
    create_client()
```

to

```
else:
    return create_client()
```

Now, not a direct answer, but you really shouldn't use recursion in this case, it is better with a loop:

```
def create_client():
    while True:
        client_type = input()

        if client_type == 'Mickey':
            return 'Mickey'
        elif client_type == 'Jenny':
            return 'Jenny'
        elif client_type == 'McElroy':
            return 'McElroy'
```

That won't exhaust the recursive call stack, and saves resources.

I would even go ahead and use a `dict` instead of a sequence of `if`/`elif`:

```
client_types = {
    'Mickey':  (3, 5, 2),
    'Jenny':   (5, 2, 3),
    'McElroy': (4, 1, 5),
}
```

then you can make your code search the dict and return the correct numbers:

```
while True:
    t = input()
    if t in client_types:
        break
client = functions.client(*client_types[t])
```